# Passing a list of numbers to a function in C++ without building array first?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I'm trying to build a function that accepts an array in the following manner:

```
int inCommon = findCommon({54,56,2,10}, 4);

int findCommon(int nums[], int len){
  for(int i=0; i<len; i++)  cout<<nums[i]<<endl;
  return 1;
}
```

Note, that's not actually what my function does, but I do loop through the array. I'm just trying to determine if it's possible to pass an array like {54,56,2,10} instead of having to create an array and pass it? (like this:

```
int theArray[]= {54,56,2,10};
int inCommon = findCommon(theArray,4);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible at the time. However, in the next C++ standard C++0x, this will be done using initalizer lists:

```
int findCommon(std::initializer_list<int> nums)
{
    std::initializer_list<int>::iterator it;
    for (it = nums.begin() ; it != nums.end() ; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;  
    }
    return 1;
}
```

See [this presentation](http://iap.cse.tamu.edu/IAP_Initializers) from Bjarne Stroustrup, and [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Initializer_lists) from Wikipedia

If you want to try C++0x features, you can check the [last versions of gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), that supports some of them.

Comment: GCC 4.4 supports initializer lists, getting the darwin port of it right now. Thanks!

Comment: nice PDF. it also contains a link to the google video ( http://video.google.de/videoplay?docid=5262479012306588324 ) of bjarne about this.

Comment: time to update the answer... or retag the question as C++98, I always wonder whats the best way to deal with such cases

Answer (score 3):

You need C++0x!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Initializer_lists

Answer (score 2):

No, I believe {} may only be used to initialize an array.

Comment: Ah, figured as much, just wanted to see if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want to do using [variable argument lists](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html).

Comment: Maybe, but those are a notoriously unsafe piece of baggage inherited from C, and in modern C++ where things like `std::initializer_list` and parameter-packs are available, they serve no useful purpose and shouldn't be recommended. Of course, since you answered before C++11 came out, that's fair enough; I'm just clarifying from today's perspective.

Comment: Ya might consider answering the question then.

Comment: Why would I do that when others already have? Including you. I wasn't saying the answer was invalid, just that varargs are now outclassed. Chill out.

Answer (score 1):

no. It is impossible.
But you can create something like template T* arrayCreator(...) function which will create your array,
Or array wrapper with constructor with unspecified arguments count.
Or create object which will have overloaded operator coma or << and will create your array, findCommon( arrCreator() << 1 << 2 << 3 << 5, other parammeters ) - this method more type safe
Or waiting C++0x implementation.