# List initializer

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to declare an iterator of type `std::initializer_list` as it is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643617/passing-a-list-of-numbers-to-a-function-in-c-without-building-array-first/643668#643668).

But I always get this error:

```
error: 'iterator' is not a member of 'std::initializer_list<int>'
```

How do I declare an iterator of type `std::initializer_list`?

The following code for example will not work. In addition, the compiler that I use supports the new standard draft.

```
int findCommon(std::initializer_list<int> nums)
{
    std::initializer_list<int>::iterator it;
    for (it = nums.begin() ; it != nums.end() ; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: First, we'll have to see your code to help.

Comment: Second, what compiler are you using? Initializer lists are only in gcc 4.4 and onwards.

Comment: yes, as I said the compiler support the new standard..

Comment: No compiler fully supports the new standard. (And how could they, while the new standard isn't even released yet?) But many compilers support the anticipated standard to some extend. That's why you would need to post the compiler and compiler version your using.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add

```
#include <initializer_list>
```

and for this example probably also

```
#include <iostream>
```

Also make sure you are using the `-std=c++0x` switch to g++. And you need at least g++ version 4.4. <strike>When using the compiler from MacPorts, the compiler is called `g++-mp-4.5` or `g++-mp-4.4`.</strike> (Incorrect assumption).

I noticed some recently fixed bugs related to `initializer_list` on the [GCC bugzilla](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla), so I recommend getting the **newest** version of GCC, 4.5.1. Because when using this version I am able to compile both your examples without problems.

Comment: it doesn't help. I can initialize data structure from the type std::initializer_list<int> and it works well. But I just can't declare the iterator for it

Comment: @sami, on my Mac, with g++ from MacPorts, your code compiles when I add the two #includes. Can you post the exact command line you use for compiling?

Comment: As I said, I don't have problem by using the the new draft. I can use the variadic template and initialize_list. The only problem is by declaring the iterator from the type  std::initialize_list. the command that I use is g++ -std=c++0x example.cpp -o example

Comment: why I can declare a data structure like std::initializer_list<int> Nr; but I cann't declare an iterator for it like  std::initializer_list<int>::iterator it;

Comment: @sami, have you tried `g++-mp-4.5` instead of `g++`? I can't see any other problem.

Comment: You might also want to check out the sourceof the initializer_list, if there really is an iterator defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler's implementation probably just doesn't have these typedefs (e.g with GCC 4.4.1, `initializer_list` doesn't contain any typedefs, you can check the header yourself).

As a "workaround", use `auto`:

```
int findCommon(std::initializer_list<int> nums)
{
    for (auto it = nums.begin() ; it != nums.end() ; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Or rely on `initializer_list<T>::iterator` being a synonym for `const T*`.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid directly specifying the iterator type, which should lead to cleaner code:

```
void f(std::initializer_list<int> nums)
{
  for (auto x : nums) {
    std::cout << x << '\n';
  }
  // or:
  std::copy(begin(nums), end(nums), std::ostream_iterator(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Range-based for loops are [supported in GCC 4.6](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).  (Any problem calling them foreach loops, informally?)

Including <iterator> may be required for std::begin and std::end, though several headers guarantee they are declared (24.6.5, N3092).